# Six cards are selected from a standard deck of cards. Determine the probability that exactly 4 of them are hearts.

Tags: probability

Six cards are selected from a standard deck of cards. Determine the probability that exactly 4 of them are hearts.(there are 13 hearts and 52 cards in total).

Comment: What have you tried? How many ways are there to pick six cards? How many ways are there to pick exactly $4$ hearts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I am sorry. I was so confused about the problem. The actual solution goes like this.
Sample Space: total number of  ways you can choose 6 cards from 52, s= $52 \choose 6$
Now, in order to choose exactly 4 hearts(out of 13), you have to choose 2 non-hearts(out of remaining 39), each of which have $13 \choose 4$ and $39 \choose 2$ ways.
Total outcomes, o = $ {13} \choose {4}$${39 \choose 2}$

Thus, the probability is, $ \frac {o}{s}$

Comment: is there nCr button? use that. otherwise, please learn about Combinations here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination or wherever you want.

Comment: In the question it says that, SIX cards are selected, so is it the probability of getting 4 hearts out of 6 cards instead of the probability of getting 4 hearts out of 4 cards? or no?

Comment: The solution first calculates the probability of getting 4 hearts without considering the case that 6 are chosen, i.e. only 4 are chosen. Now that, we have plain probability of getting 4 hearts out of 4 cards, we move to the actual question: 4 hearts when 6 cards chosen. If you have chosen 6 cards, then $ 6 \choose 4 $ is the number of ways you can choose 4 cards from 6 and after getting the number of ways, we multiply it by the plain probability obtained before.

Comment: Can I also answer the question in this way too? Is this answer correct or wrong? and why? https://i.imgur.com/yJKBAUo.png (its a picture, i cant upload pictures to comments on stack exchange)

Comment: that's correct!! And I am afraid, My solution was incorrect. Sorry!!

Comment: I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find:
$$P(HHHHH'H')+\cdots+P(H'H'HHHH).$$
Note that all of them are equally likely and the number of them is:
$$C_4^6=15.$$
Hence:
$$P(4 \ hearts \ in \ 6 \ cards)=15\cdot P(HHHHH'H')=0.026.$$